# why l cant have permission to access to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, firebase-security

I've some apps working with Firebase using database, but the problem is why l dont have permission to access the desired data to firebase database ?

[image]

```
   {
      "rules": {
        "profile": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "true",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]
  main code

```
ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.fire.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){

        this.toastCtrl.create({
          message : ` welcome ${data.email}`,
          duration:2000
        }).present()

        this.itemRef  = this.db.object(`report/profile/${data.uid}`);
            this.item = this.itemRef.valueChanges();


      }

    })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as I see in your screenshot, you're trying to access `/`.  But you've only granted access to `/profile/$uid`.  If you don't grant access to it, it's not readable from mobile clients.  Or perhaps you meant to use a more specific path in the emulator to test?

Comment: `/profile` isn't going to work either.  You must give the full path where access is allowed, and that requires a uid part.